# Keeping selected item from dropdown box after page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown box with a list of times for the user to choose from. My problem is that after the user picks their choice and then hits the submit button, the page is refreshed and then the dropdown box is set to default again - how can i have the users choice stay in the dropdown box even after a page reload? I am not sure what part of my code is needed best my Get and Post are long - but if there is a general example that would help.

CODE FROM CONTROLLER:

Here is one of my lists i load into the dropdown box:

```
IQueryable<User> users = _userRepository.FindAllForOffice(_currentUser.OfficeId);
            userViewModel.Users = users.ToSelectList("UserId", "FullName",
                                                                   userViewModel.UserId.ToString());

            foreach (SelectListItem view in userViewModel.Users)
            {
                if (!viewData.ContainsKey(view.Text))
                    viewData.Add(view.Text, view.Value + "|user");
            }
```

This is adding to the actual dropdown:

```
userViewModel.ViewData = viewData.ToSelectList("Value", "Key",
                                                                         userViewModel.Value);
            return View("UserSummary", userViewModel);
```

ON MY ASPX.CS page i have the following:

Page_Load

```
string viewType = null;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["viewType"]))
        {
            viewType = Request.QueryString["viewType"];
        }


if(!IsPostBack)
        { if (viewType == "user")
                {
                    viewParams.Add("ViewName", "User Report");
                    var reportDataSource =
                        _userService.GetUsersReportData(beginDate, endDate, id);
                    reportViewer.Initialize("UserIndividual.rdlc",
                                            new List<ReportDataSource> {reportDataSource}, viewParams);
                }
```

I didn't add all the initialization for all the elements - didn't think it is really needed for this situation

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `SelectListItem` to populate your drop down, or are you constructing it manually yourself? Please provide a code sample to better give you a response.

Comment: @Tejs - yes i am using SelectListItem and i have added some code above. Thanks!

Comment: This almost doesn't look like ASP.NET MVC... in your view, are you calling `Html.DropDownList` or doing you own code? I'd like to see that.

Comment: Do you mean page reload as in page refresh by pressing F5?

Comment: @Dutch yes - i meant refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution which was really simple and i guess i was overlooking it. I found that the same way i was passing in the values of the dates i could pass the value of the selected view type and it will remain in dropdown box until changed rather than changing after every page load. 
I made the additions in my CONTROLLER file in my Get method after the button click.

this is my Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResultSummary(ResultSummaryViewModel resultSummaryViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("ResultSummary", resultSummaryViewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("ResultSummary",
                                new
                                    {
                                        beginDate = resultSummaryViewModel.BeginDate,
                                        endDate = resultSummaryViewModel.EndDate,
                                        value = resultSummaryViewModel.Value
                                    });
    }
```

And this is my Get:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ResultSummary(DateTime? beginDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, string value="")
    {
        var resultSummaryViewModel = new ResultSummaryViewModel();
        resultSummaryViewModel.BeginDate = beginDate;
        resultSummaryViewModel.EndDate = endDate;
        resultSummaryViewModel.Value = value;
```

.........

The code continues but this is the main part.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this odetocode.com article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx) out.

To keep the selected value after a manual refresh, you could use a cookie, for example `jquery.cookie`. You would have to save the selected value on change and retrieve the value on page load.

Comment: I really like this example thanks Dutch. But i am not using IEnumarable so i will see a close alternative. Again thanks i am sure i will refer to this in the future.

Comment: IQueryable is an IEnumerable, SelectList is an IEnumerable and userViewModel.Users is an IEnumerable'as well.